# CQL_filter parameter on WMS layer doesn't work

Tags: geoserver, wms, cql-filter

I am trying to filter my WMS layer using CQL_filter parameter as:

```
 wms_layer =  new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Larisa","http://localhost/geoserver/gwc/service/wms",
            {
                layers: 'esot:clusternodes_', 
                format:  "image/png",
                CQL_FILTER: 'cluster=1',
                transparent: true,
                version: "1.1.1"
            },
            {
                displayOutsideMaxExtent: false,
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
            }
        );

 map.addLayer(wms_layer);
```

For some reason the filter doesn't work and all the layer is shown on the map. 
I have checked the version and it must be correct. I use OpenLayers 2.12 and my GeoServer is 2.6.0.

I have tried to remove from the layer the workspace name ('esot') but then the layer fails completely to load.

Comment: Does the same request work if you send the request directly to GeoServer, rather than using OpenLayers to construct it first?

Comment: Nope. If I execute the request on my browser I get again all the layer: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?LAYERS=esoteriko%3Aclusternodes_&VERSION=1.1.1&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&CQL_FILTER=cluster%3D100&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A900913&BBOX=2494904.6028809,4808806.3228076,2499796.5726904,4813698.2926172&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually making a GeoWebCache request not a simple WMS request so in general GWC ignores filters. The simple answer is to make your filtered request directly to GeoServer by changing `http://localhost/geoserver/gwc/service/wms` to `http://localhost/geoserver/wms` and all will work as you expect. This is the easiest answer as you are unlikely to want to cache the filtered layers anyway.

The other solution is to configure your cached layer to handle filters see this [manual page](https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/configuration/layers/parameterfilters.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was fighting with this so much time. I have tried everything but couldn't figure it out. I even tried to send the request without the 'gwc' part but I have left the 'service'. Now it works perfectly and a big questionmark in my head has disappeared! Thanks :)